# Getting FragmentResultListener triggered without popbackstack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Currently I'm facing a problem getting data from a child fragment to it's parent fragment, I saw that the best option is using `setFragmentResult` but because `setFragmentResultListener` needs to be in `STARTED` state at parentFragment(doen't happen because it is stoped when replaced by another fragment) I see that the only option is to use `popBackStack()` and then the listener gets triggered. The thing is that I don't wanna use `popBackStack()`

Can anyone help me?

PS: No, I don't want to use viewModel in this case to keep data.

Listener:

```
class ResultListenerFragment : Fragment() {
val viewModel : SomeViewModel by viewModels()
var result : String? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
        //verify values
       viewModel.repeat()
    }
//in case of an error       
 viewModel.getError().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
     requireActivity()
    .supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.framelayout, ErrorFragment.newInstance(it).commit()
   }
  }
}
```

Triggerer:

```
class ErrorFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_error) {
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    view.findViewById(R.id.some_tv).text = arguments.getString(keyError)
    view.findViewById(R.id.result_button).setOnClickListener {
        val result = "retry"
        // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
        setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to result))
    }
  }
companion object {
   private const val keyError = "errorKey"
   fun newInstance(error:String): ErrorFragment{
       val args = Bundle().apply {
                putString(keyError, error)
            }
       }
      return ErrorFragment().apply{arguments = args}
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The code you pasted is for sending results between sibling fragments (i.e., Fragments in the same FragmentManager), not sending results from a child fragment to its parent fragment. Which is it that you are trying to do? Can you explain what fragments in your child/parent relationship are on the back stack?

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you, for showing interest in my problem.
 I edited it, for somewhat the problem that I have. Maybe I misunderstood the concept of child/parent fragment, but in the code above, it is something like that. Reminder that these fragments can't share same viewModel.